# Why git sometimes shows that a file was changed when it was not?

Tags: git, git-commit, gitweb

DragonFly BSD uses git as its SCM, with one single repository and branch for both the kernel and the whole userland.

On 2011-11-26, someone did a commit that somehow touched every single file in the repository, even though most files were not changed at all.

That's the offending commit from 2011-11-26: 
http://gitweb.dragonflybsd.org/dragonfly.git/commitdiff/86d7f5d305c6adaa56ff4582ece9859d73106103 
 https://github.com/DragonFlyBSD/DragonFlyBSD/commit/86d7f5d305c6adaa56ff4582ece9859d73106103

Since then, with some tools, if you look at file history for any file anywhere in the repo, you can see that it was changed on 2011-11-26 with that commit, but it's only shown in some tools, and not shown in others.

For example, the bogus 2011-11-26 commit **is not shown** with the following tools:

- `git log sys/sys/sensors.h`
- https://github.com/DragonFlyBSD/DragonFlyBSD/commits/master/sys/sys/sensors.h

However, the bogus commit **is erroneously shown** with the following:

- `git whatchanged --pretty=%at sys/sys/sensors.h`

  ```
  1322296064

  :000000 100644 0000000... 554cfc2... A  sys/sys/sensors.h
  1191329821

  :000000 100644 0000000... 554cfc2... A  sys/sys/sensors.h
  ```

  The 1322296064 time is the bogus one, and notice how the file was `A`dded without ever being deleted, and that the `dst` sha1 is the same.  Another, more representative example, which shows that `src` sha1 is always `0000000...` in such bogus commits, even though it makes little sense when you consider that the file was never deleted and still has the same `dst` sha1:

  ```
  % git whatchanged --pretty=%at sys/sys/sysctl.h | head -9
  1322296064

  :000000 100644 0000000... 6659977... A  sys/sys/sysctl.h
  1296826445

  :100644 100644 94b8d96... 6659977... M  sys/sys/sysctl.h
  1292413105

  :100644 100644 8c9deaa... 94b8d96... M  sys/sys/sysctl.h
  ```
- http://gitweb.dragonflybsd.org/dragonfly.git/history/HEAD:/sys/sys/sensors.h

My **questions** are as follows:

- How was it possible for the files to be added without first being deleted in the first place?  Was / is it a bug in git to allow something like that?
- Why do some tools compact such bogus commits out (and hide them from the user), but some don't?
- Is there a way to make `git-whatchanged` and `gitweb` ignore such bogus commits on files that weren't actually modified, just as `git-log` and `github` do?

Answer (score 2):

I had look at the commit in question and found the answer:

It is a “root commit” – it doesn’t have any parents. Usually the only commit in the repo that has this property is the first commit ever.

So every file in this commit is indeed new, because there exists no older version.

`git log` filters out this commit because it is not the first parent at the merge point. I don’t know the logic that leads `git log` to believe that there is something to ignore in the first place.

No, there is no way to make the other tools ignore such commits, because they are just doing their job.

What went wrong here is that this commit should never have been created without a parent and if somebody creates a commit like this, it should never be merged anywhere.